# VS 2008 C++ how to make a project without .net dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am writing a plain vanilla c++ console app using VS 2008. When I create the project, the IDE gives me a choice of .net versions. There is no option for 'none'. When I look at the project properties page, the Targeted Framework has whatever value I chose and is greyed out.

When I try and run the app on a windows machine without the clr, it gives me a setup error and quits.

There is nothing in my code that has anything to do with .net. How can I escape the clutches of .net and the clr?

Comment: resolving the error might be a step in the good direction, what is it exactly?

Comment: Even more interesting, when I look at the executable in a text viewer, it has the notation 'This program cannot be run in DOS mode.' So it even says I can't do what I need to do.

Comment: That text appears in all win32 programs - it's talking about MS-DOS (remember that? 8-), not the Windows command prompt.  You can't run a Windows console program under MS-DOS.

Comment: This phrase appears in every single PE executable file (EXE, DLL, OCX...) so you shouldn't worry about that

Comment: That's comforting.
Anyway the error is 'The application failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling may fix this problem.
This occurs on a machine without the clr installed. On two other machines which have the clr, it runs fine.

Comment: that has nothing to do with .NET. The problem is the language runtime. When asking a question, it's usually a good idea to describe the problem, not what you think the solution is. Asking about .NET dependencies is just likely to get you wrong answers, when you're not actually getting a .NET-related error ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you chose the "Win32 Console Application" project type.  This will give you a C++ only project.  Most of the other console options will bind the project to .Net.

Answer (score 5):

How are you creating the project?  If I start Visual Studio 2008 and go File / New / Project... / Other languages / Visual C++ / Win32 / Win32 Console Application, I get a plain old C++ project with no .net dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Just choose Win32 Console Application.  The drop down at the top of the window is irrelevant.

[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2029/screenmzi.jpg](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2029/screenmzi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The problem (based on your comment under the question) has nothing to do with .NET.

The problem is most likely how you link to the C runtime library.
Visual Studio defaults to using the dynamically linked (dll) version, which means that dll has to be present on the target machine.

The simple fix is to change your project to use the statically linked version.
Under project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation, set Runtime Library to Multi-Threaded or Multi-Threaded Debug (but **not** Multi-Threaded (debug) DLL).

Alternatively, you have to deploy the runtime dll along with your program.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you right click the project in the solution explorer and go to Properties->Configuration Properties->General

You should be satisfied to see that the "Common language support" field should be set to "No common language support" if you followed the above advice i.e. compiling with no clr !

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out which DLLs are needed to yours program. May be problem is not with .NET, and with Runtime or ATL libraries. Did you used static linkage?